# django: passing a url as a parameter

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

I want to pass a URL from javascript to a django view. I have the following urls.py

```
     --- urls.py ---
     url(r'^show/(?P<url>\.+)$', 'myapp.views.jsonProcess'),
```

The view has the following declaration:

```
    --- views.py ---
    def jsonProcess(request, url):
```

The URL I pass in javascript is as follows:

```
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/show/' + 'http://www.google.com';
    window.open(url);
```

I get a "Page not Found (404)" error while matching the URL. What am I missing? Any, and all pointers are welcome since I am hopelessly stuck! :(

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, you don't need to escape the dot if you want it to mean any symbol (in `urls.py`).

```
url(r'^show/(?P<url>.+)$', 'myapp.views.json_process')
```

Secondly, use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to properly escape the parameter.

```
var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/show/' +
    encodeURIComponent('http://www.google.com')
```

---

By the way, don't use [mixedCase for function names](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) in Python:

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
>   underscores as necessary to improve readability.

---

Another note that might help in future: don't hardcode Django URLs in JavaScript. You can generate them dynamically either [in your views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
url = reverse(
    'myapp.views.json_process',
    kwargs={'url': 'http://www.google.com'}
)
```

Or [in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url):

```
{% url myapp.views.json_process url="http://www.google.com" %}
```

Comment: That worked! I was escaping the dot. Thank you! :) I'll keep the naming convention in mind... I'm relatively new to python!

Comment: what if for example I'd like to pass a parameter that is a javascript? ` var query = document.getElementById("search").value;  url_page = url + "{% url 'city_view' query=query%}";`